# I try to insert this data into this tables but i got errror with High prority.I use MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

The query :

```
INSERT INTO tabticket

(name,creation,modified,modified_by,owner,docstatus,parent,parentfield,parent_type,idx,problem_status,commune,wiring_problem,actual_repair_visit_date,high_priority,vil

lage,solved_date,shs_id,customer_name,bottow_red_light,consumption,title,_comments,state,repair_comment,technician_required,plug_solar_plane,problem_description,teachn

ician_id,province,battery_level,_liked_by,planed_repair_visit_date,_assign,teachnician_name,phone,district,clean_panel,_user_tags,repairs_done,customer_id,product_type

,use_system,charge_led,opening_ticket-date,top_red_light,ticket_status,plug_solar_panel,bottom_red_light)
VALUES('ticket-00782','2016-09-01 010:20:07.634000','2016-09-01 10:30:07.634000','kalyan@kamworks.com','kalyan@kamworks.com',0,'NULL','NULL',NULL,0,'','ខុនរ៉ង Khon Rang- 

040104',' ','NULL',0,'កំពង់អួរ Kampong Uor - 04010410','NULL','SHS100 163','Som Sophat','NULL','0','NULL','NULL','0','NULL',' ',NULL,'no power','NULL','កំពង់ឆ្នាំង Kampong 

Chhnang',' ','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','097 5 005 554','បរិបូណ៌ Baribour - 0401','NULL',0,'040000049','SHS 100W -v2.0',' ',' ','2016-09-01','Pending repair visit',' ',' ');
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that                corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'high_priority,village,solved_date,shs_id,customer_name,bottow_red_light,consumpt' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

Always use a SQL statement to check your statement, you don't need to post this if you have those tools.

First, `high_priority` is part of mysql [select statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) **reserved word**. If you use it as your column name, you must explicitly use quotation mark to prevent the query engine treat it as part of command.

Second,  `opening_ticket-DATE` are going to give you error, after you fix `high_priority` with a quote. Again, without a quote, mysql query just treat the "-" mark as arithmetic operator, .e.g. opening_ticket (minus) DATE.

This is a terrible RBMS table structure, it is not normalised and doesn't standardise naming convention.

For example, I will use "priority" as the column name, limit the value to "low,medium,high" or "1,5,10" , this will allow assignment depends on written algorithm.